# WatiN SelectList or DIV Click from Google Adwords Keywords Page

Tags: watin, web-scraping, selectlist, google-ads-api

I have tried everything but no luck. I am using Watin and C# .NET

What I am doing is going to:

> https ://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none

**Note:** There's no space between `https` and `://`, but I had to add it because of a markdown problem

Entering the captcha manually (typing the text from Watin).

After you search for keywords, you will see that in the bottom of the page you have a *Next* and a *Previous* button.

I would like from WatiN to go to page 2, 3,...

It sounds simple, click on the `div` (with *id* `gwt-debug-aw-paging-next` ) and it will go to next page, but it does not happen.

I tried `FireEvent`, `click`, `KeyDown`, everything ... but it's not working.

I also tried to select 100 results from the `Selectlist`, but again, it does not work.

I tried it in all ways:

```
browser.DomContainer.SelectList("gwt-debug-aw-paging-list-box").Option("100").Select();
```

Nothing seems to work when talking about the buttons from the bottom right of the page.

I managed to "simulate" the click on *Broad* or *Exact results*, but not with the bottom buttons.

Any suggestions?

**Edit 1**:
I uploaded an image so you can see exactly the button I am talking about:

[image: example]

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX7Yi.jpg) to view it larger.

```
<div id="gwt-debug-aw-paging-next" class="goog-button-base goog-inline-block goog-button aw-btn aw-pagination-button" tabindex="0" title="Next page">
<input type="text" tabindex="-1" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
<div class="goog-button-base-outer-box goog-inline-block">
<div class="goog-button-base-inner-box goog-inline-block">
<div class="goog-button-base-pos">
<div class="goog-button-base-top-shadow">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="goog-button-base-content">
<span id="gwt-debug-aw-paging-next-content" class="aw-pagination-next">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please paste the markup of the element you would like to click, including a parent element or two.

This will help in suggesting solutions.

Thanks.

---

So the following does not work?

```
using(IE ie = new IE("your-page's-url"))
{
    // ... any steps needed to bring up the page in question ...
    ie.Element("gwt-debug-aw-paging-next").Click();
}
```

If not, maybe try clicking on the span gwt-debug-aw-paging-next-content.

Comment: I tried clicking on the span, tried clicking on the div. Tried Click, tried FireEvent, tried Focus + KeyboardDown ... everything. Still need help with this :(

Comment: I have did more tests and it seems that in Watin, I don't get the entire HTML code. When I go from the browser (Firefox with firebug) I get an <input type="text"> right after the first DIV. But when I do it from Watin, I don't see that element. I tried to look over the HTML and from Watin, I have 3 div's with the same ID, but in firefox I don't. What can be the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. Another programmer gave me this tip, so the credits go to him.

The idea is that there are more spans with the same ID in google adwords (strange, I know), so what we need to do is click on every span, not only at the first span.

Here is the final code that needs to be added:

```
var pagination = browser.Spans.Where(e =>
e.IdOrName == "gwt-debug-aw-paging-next-content").ToList();

foreach (var item in pagination)
item.Click();
```